My question was falsely removed as rude and abusive
This question has recently been deleted as rude and abusive for what appears to be no real reason. While I must admit it isn't my finest work and probably should have been closed as 'Opinion-Based', there is no basis whatsoever to go to the nuclear option of completely wiping it as abuse. What can we do to rectify this?

Several Things You Can Do!

You should be asking questions about worldbuilding. Apart from its other issues, the question you asked is really a very bad plot question. You're asking about the actions of a character rather than about some aspect of the world.

You should not be asking blatantly vulgar questions. It's up to you as querent to understand basic social norms when interacting in public and up to you to restrain yourself about such topics. We do have kids here. WB.SE is fairly cool with asking clinically worded questions that ask about sexual or violent topics. Key word here is clinical. You went way over that line.

You are correct that your query could have been closed as opinion based. Also storybuilding. Also for not being a worldbuilding question. This is not an excuse for you to write a vulgar question. You should continue writing on topic questions that don't cross common sense community standards and that do not run afoul of various closure reasons.



So I should've clinically explained how 69ing works? Or would you dismiss that as vulgarity too?

@IchthysKing -- No. That's a) inappropriate for this forum and b) off topic for being story based. Just give it up. You shouldn't have brought that up at all. You really should also delete your comment.

If you really think a weird sport is more "inappropriate" than the well-upvoted discussions of torture on this site, I don't know what to say

@IchthysKing It’s not a sports question. To pretend that it was is a gross misrepresentation of fact. The question clearly violates SE’s sensitive content policy. Adding additional details describing a sex act, regardless of if you are using clinical language, is inappropriate for this site.

@IchthysKing --- Just stop, please. This was not a weird sports question. You have a very strong pattern of asking highly fetishy questions. You actually do know how to write good questions here. I'd suggest you stop writing about your private fantasies and continue writing good worldbuilding questions.

You have already stepped on gunky ground with the question about anatomically correct phalli, which has received 7 downvotes and 0 upvotes and a good shower of comments pointing out how much out of place it was.
Apparently that has not been sufficient to make you understand what is the limit.
If you don't want questions to be closed as rude, try not asking questions with content which can be seen as rude, questionable or simply aiming at titillating the lower instincts of the public.

There are places to ask such questions.  Might I suggest https://www.reddit.com/r/NSFWworldbuilding/?  Obviously, given that subreddit's name, its content is NSFW, so be careful about clicking that link.
Worldbuilding Stackexchange is not the place.  It is possible to ask questions here about sex, but such questions must maintain a clinical air and avoid prurience.  Your deleted question clearly did not meet those criteria.
The question was automatically deleted by Stack Exchange's automated processes in response to user flags labelling it as spam or offensive.  No moderator closed or deleted the question.
Given the subject matter of the question and the manner of its closure, I am unwilling to undelete or reopen it, and I doubt that any other WB SE moderator would be willing to do so either.  L.Dutch's opinion is also on record here as an answer.

@JBH "an automated system that tests questions against a set of unpublished Stack Exchange heuristics," the bot does no such thing. There is some automation done via Community. For example, occasionally it will bump posts for visibility. Community is attributed ownership of some system actions on the platform. If enough users cast a spam or rude flag on a post, then that post is removed. The attribution goes to Community but it's a system action that happened. Automatic deletions happen but the criteria is known and takes a minimum of 10 days.

I wasn't part of the original issue and read the question for the first time by clicking the link in this post.
The question is not as objective as one might think
Considering there the range of sexual sensitivity is as great as there are shades of human skin (if not a lot more) answers to your question would have been entirely opinion-based and fundamentally irrelevant. Said another way, whether or not your proposed problem should err on one side or another is a matter of narrative necessity (aka, off-topic storybuilding). The only practical answer is, "yes, if that's what you want."
There may come a time when story-based questions are permitted. That appears to be the trend in the ongoing effort to revamp the Help Center and it's certainly true that, generally, people like answering story questions... perhaps even more than actual worldbuilding questions... but such is not the case today. And to reiterate: the question does not have an objective and deterministic answer.
The Real World Question policy
Having said that, there is the real world question policy which could be used to justify your question. I originally supported this policy. Ignoring all other things, at best your question is permissible here only because of that policy.
I no longer support the policy without an actual change to the Real World. The original goal was to increase the number of questions on the still-growing site. Over time (and I am guilty of this myself) the policy has been abused to ask physics, chemistry, biology, mathematics, etc. questions that, themselves, have no actual relation to worldbuilding. They're just free research questions.
Well... time has passed and we no longer need all those extra questions. In fact, I think that policy has contributed to a decidedly negative trend on WB.SE toward the infernal quest for "as realistic as possible" fiction. Simply put, your question appears to be nothing more than a biology question in the context of the Real World (no worldbuilding involved) and should have been submitted to Biology.SE. But if you choose to do that, I strongly suggest you avoid your story context, because...
This community-moderated service is NOT a free-for-all
This service is supported by a very large number of users from all over the world. Users with a widely varying set of morals, mores, and sensitivities — at least two of whom felt your question was in poor taste. The reality is that while few of any of those many users would complain about a creature-design question seeking help developing the sexuality of a fictional race, it's little wonder that people complained about a question that to many (myself included) was just asking for help writing pornography.
Don't forget the most important thing
Finally, it's worth noting that you have learned an important thing: you've learned a practical limit of what will and will not be tolerated on this Stack.

+1 for point 4.
